Error CS0815 No se puede asignar un void a una variable con tipo explícito
Tengo el "Error CS0815 No se puede asignar un void a una variable con tipo explícito", al  El error está en ´var result = await _postRepository.DeletePost(id);´
    namespace SocialMedia.Api.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class PostController : ControllerBase
        {
            private readonly IPostRepository _postRepository;
            private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    
            public PostController(IPostRepository postRepository, IMapper mapper)
            {
                _postRepository = postRepository;
                _mapper = mapper;
            }
    
            [HttpGet]
            public async Task<IActionResult> GetPosts()
            {
                var posts = await _postRepository.GetPosts();
                var postsDto = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PostDto>>(posts);
    
                return Ok(postsDto);
            }
    
            [HttpGet("{id}")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> GetPost(int id)
           {
               var post = await _postRepository.GetPost(id);
               var postDto = _mapper.Map<PostDto>(post);
   
               return Ok(postDto);
           }
   
           [HttpPost]
           public async Task<IActionResult> Post(PostDto postDto)
           {
               var post = _mapper.Map<Post>(postDto);
   
               await _postRepository.InsertPost(post);
               return Ok(post);
           }
   
           [HttpPut]
           public async Task<IActionResult> Put(int id, PostDto postDto)
           {
               var post = _mapper.Map<Post>(postDto);
               post.PostId = id;
   
               await _postRepository.UpdatePost(post);
               return Ok(post);
           }
   
           [HttpDelete]
           public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
           {
               var result = await _postRepository.DeletePost(id);
               return Ok(result);
           }
       }
   }

Este se da al momento de usar la variable que necesito usar para eliminar un registro mediante el método "Delete" en mi archivo PostController.cs. Ya tengo todos los 'using' AutoMapper, AspNetCore, DTOs, Entities, Interfaces.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Cual es la firma de este metodo?_postRepository.DeletePost(id);

Agrega _postRepository.DeletePost(id) supongo que este método retorna "void"
